# Docker + GitLab CI - Tag image as "latest" after successful test

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to tag auto-built Docker images on my private Registry within GitLab-CI, but the 'release' job fails with:
`Error response from daemon: No such image: dev.skibapro.de:5050/dransfeld/dockerci-test:v0.4`

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the build and test jobs run without errors and docerci-test:v0.4 is present in my Registry after the pipeline has run.

```
image: docker:stable
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  only:
    - tags
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG -f docker/Dockerfile .
  - docker push $IMAGE_TAG

test:
  only:
    - tags
  stage: test
  script:
  - docker run $IMAGE_TAG /usr/local/bin/test.sh

release:
  only:
    - tags
  stage: release
  script:
  - docker tag $IMAGE_TAG "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
```

This is the error I'm getting in the job log:

```
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
$ docker tag $IMAGE_TAG "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
Error response from daemon: No such image: dev.skibapro.de:5050/dransfeld/dockerci-test:v0.4
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I don't know it the image just isn't present yet when the 'release' stage runs, or if I'm asking docker to do something it can't... I want the latest tag to only be applied after the test stage finished successfully.

Answer (score 6):

Altough Docker seems to support tagging images in remote registries ([Add remote tag to a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763427/add-remote-tag-to-a-docker-image)), GitLab needs to pull the image from the remote registry first. From GitLab's Blog (https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/)

```
release-image:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
    - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
```