# How do you tag a Docker Manifest

Tags: docker, manifest

Specifically, we're doing development in both x64 and ARM64, so our :latest tag needs to do both.

Ideally, something like this would work

```
docker manifest create --amend my_repo:date my_repo:date-arm64 myrepo:date-amd64
docker manifest push my_repo:date
docker tag my_repo:date my_repo:latest
docker push my_repo:latest
```

except that when I do that, I get a message saying

```
23:52:49  Created manifest list docker.io/my_repo:date
23:52:50  sha256:blahblah
23:52:50  Error response from daemon: No such image: my_repo:date
```

Is there any way of doing this other than creating and pushing another manifest object?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70532501/596285

Comment: No, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526615/1981986 does.